# Default option in array

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I set 'By Email' as the default option in the following array?
In the worst case the other options may also be deleted completely.

```
            array(
                'name'              => __( 'Job Apply Type', 'wp-job-board-pro' ),
                'id'                => $prefix . 'apply_type',
                'type'              => 'select',
                'options'           => array(
                    'with_email' => __( 'By Email', 'wp-job-board-pro' ),
                    'external' => __( 'External URL', 'wp-job-board-pro' ),
                    'internal' => __( 'Internal', 'wp-job-board-pro' ),
                )
            ),
            array(
                'name'              => __( 'External URL for Apply Job', 'wp-job-board-pro' ),
                'id'                => $prefix . 'apply_url',
                'type'              => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'name'              => __( 'Job Apply Email', 'wp-job-board-pro' ),
                'id'                => $prefix . 'apply_email',
                'type'              => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'name'              => __( 'Min. Salary', 'wp-job-board-pro' ),
                'id'                => $prefix . 'salary',
                'type'              => 'text',
                'field_call_back' => array( 'WP_Job_Board_Pro_Abstract_Filter', 'filter_field_job_salary'),
            ),
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by default?  Can you give us an example of what you would like the output to be given that input?

Comment: @DanielleCox: Now the field is empty. If you click on it you will get the three options described. I actually want the field not to be empty and one specific option is already chosen by default.
If this is difficult to achieve, an alternative is to drop the options and opt for one standard.